# SQL Server return date range and associated value between specified values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm fetching records from the DB using a query like:

```
SELECT date as "Date", count(date) as "NumIssues"
FROM Issues
WHERE Date BETWEEN '2015-03-25' AND '2015-03-28'
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date;
```

The query works fine but I need it to fetch results even if there are no values for the specified date and return 0 for the NumIssues value.

Would the best way to go about this would be to put in case statements? Thanks in advance!

Comment: One way is to join the query with a table of dates (or some construct that generates all the dates between the specified dates).

Comment: To generate the list of dates between 2 specified dates can be done using the dates common table expression in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;WITH dates ( "Date" ) AS (
    SELECT  CONVERT( DATE, '2015-03-25' )
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  DATEADD( DAY, 1, Date )
    FROM    dates
    WHERE   DATEADD( DAY, 1, Date ) < '2015-03-28'
)
SELECT  d.Date
,       COUNT(date) as "NumIssues"
FROM    dates AS d
LEFT JOIN Issues AS i
    ON  i.date = d.Date
GROUP  BY d.date
ORDER  BY d.date;
```

Comment: This is almost it! Only thing is that the NumIssue values for Dates 26-28 are showing up as 1 when they should be 0.

Comment: Perfect, that was it +1! and line 6 should be <= '2015-03-28'. Thanks a bunch!